# How to get json data after redraw of datatable?

Tags: json, laravel, yajra-datatable

When page load for the first time, I got json object returned from controller. But after deletion of a data it doesn't return json object. I mean, I can access `requestTable.ajax.json()` after initial load of `var requestTable = $('#Request-Table').DataTable({});`. But after any event when the table got redrawn, `requestTable.ajax.json()` gives an error.

My main concern is how to get value of `recordsTotal` from json object after every event. Can anyone assist me with that?

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/requests'], function () {
    Route::get('/show', [
        'uses' => 'InvitationController@show',
        'as'   => 'requests.show',
    ]);
    Route::delete('/delete/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'InvitationController@destroy',
        'as'   => 'requests.destroy',
    ]);
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function show()
{
    return Datatables::of(Invitation::query()->whereNull('invitation_token'))->make(true);
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $invitations = Invitation::where('id', $id)->delete();

    return Response::json($invitations);
}
```

**DataTable Function:**

```
// Initial Load
requestTable = $('#Request-Table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        order: [[ 3, "asc" ]],
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        ajax: '{{ route('requests.show') }}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            { 
                targets: 3,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta){
                        return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"delete-request btn btn-sm btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#Modal-Request-Delete\" data-id=\""+row.id+"\">Delete Request</button>";
                },
                searchable: false,
                orderable: false
            }
        ]
    });
});

// Delete Request
$('body').on('click', '#Btn-Delete-Request', function () {
    var requestId = $("#Delete-Request").data("id");
    $("#Delete-Request").prop('id', '');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "delete",
        url: "/requests/delete/"+requestId,
        success: function (data) {
            window.requestTable = $('#Request-Table').dataTable();
            window.requestTable.fnDraw();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to send data from delete you can just refresh your table by `ajax.reload()` function

below i put your code with modify check it's working or not

```js
// Initial Load

var requestTable ;
requestTable = $('#Request-Table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        order: [[ 3, "asc" ]],
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        ajax: '{{ route('requests.show') }}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            { 
                targets: 3,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta){
                        return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"delete-request btn btn-sm btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#Modal-Request-Delete\" data-id=\""+row.id+"\">Delete Request</button>";
                },
                searchable: false,
                orderable: false
            }
        ]
    });
});

// Delete Request
$('body').on('click', '#Btn-Delete-Request', function () {
    var requestId = $("#Delete-Request").data("id");
    $("#Delete-Request").prop('id', '');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "delete",
        url: "/requests/delete/"+requestId,
        success: function (data) {
            requestTable.ajax.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

above `var requestTable` so in delete function you can access that and `requestTable.ajax.reload();` this function you can use to refresh you table